# Inclusiones de múltiples versiones

Tags: php

Tengo un problema al manejar el sistema de versiones de mi aplicación. Quiero poder incluir en la ejecución la última versión de una libreria, pero al seleccionar un proyecto (el cual soportara una versión específica de la libreria), quiero incluir la versión de la libreria que es compatible con el proyecto.

```
Lib 1.0.0
class Validation{...

Lib 1.0.1
class Validation{...

Framework Lib = 1.0.1
Project Lib   = 1.0.0
```

Realizo un include a la libreria del framework para poder usar la ultima version de la class Validation(), pero una vez realice las validaciones, Necesito ahora incluir y usar la Lib del proyecto, ya que este es compatible solo con la antigua.
¿De que forma podría resolver esto? o ¿que me recomiendan?

Soy consciente de que esto es un metodo extraño y no muy recomendable (creo), pero quiero hacerlo y probar su factibilidad

Comment: almacena las rutas en variables y verifica la version con un if, de acuerdo con la version cargas la ruta... con el include...

Comment: Claro, de hecho no es necesario, la funcion get_included_files, ya me entrega en un array todos los archivos cargados, el tema es que si o si uso una version del archivo, para realizar validaciones y conexiones a bases de datos y otras versiones, las uso para los proyectos, esto es mas por si dentro del framework llego a tener mas de un proyecto y este no es compatible con las nuevas versiones de alguna libreria, y asi poder mantenerlas separadas y evitar esa incompatibilidad @FranciscoNúñez

Comment: pues tienes un problema de arquitectura o diseño ... segun los paradigmas de programacion una clase no debe tener mas de 1 proposito en pocas palabras no deberias de tener mas de un proyecto en tu framework... deberias tener un framework base o de partida he ir implementando las libreria segun los requerimientos...